# How to pass variable from python to HTML specific table cell

Tags: python, html, web, beautifulsoup, append

I am trying to 'append' string variable from my python code to HTML table cell. I am using BeautifulSoup4 library. My code looks like this:

```
with open("index.html") as inf:
txt = inf.read()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(txt)

soup.h3.clear()
soup.h3.append(result)

number = [str(5.555555), str(6.9420), str(9.99)]

for i in range(3):
    soup.tr.find("td", class_="class1").append(number[i])

# save the file again
with open("index.html", "w") as outf:
    outf.write(str(soup))
```

My HTML table looks like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<!---<th></th>--->
<th id="test">header1</th>
<th id="test">header2</th>
<th id="test">header3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="class1"></td>
<td class="class1"></td>
<td class="class1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="class2"></td>
<td class="class2"></td>
<td class="class2"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Please help me, my fellow programmers :)

Comment: (1) Fix the indentation of the shown code. (2) Is the shown HTML the input or the output? Also show the output/input.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `NavigableString` and `.insert()` into your soup object:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

txt = '''<table>
<tr>
<!---<th></th>--->
<th id="test">header1</th>
<th id="test">header2</th>
<th id="test">header3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="class1"></td>
<td class="class1"></td>
<td class="class1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="class2"></td>
<td class="class2"></td>
<td class="class2"></td>
</tr>
</table>'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')


number = [str(5.555555), str(6.9420), str(9.99)]

for i in range(3):
    soup.find_all("td", class_="class1")[i].insert(0, NavigableString(number[i]))
```

**Output:**

```
<table>
<tr>
<!---<th></th>--->
<th id="test">header1</th>
<th id="test">header2</th>
<th id="test">header3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="class1">5.555555</td>
<td class="class1">6.942</td>
<td class="class1">9.99</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="class2"></td>
<td class="class2"></td>
<td class="class2"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```